# Hide nth div's in a series of div based on screen size

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I have a simple photo gallery page which show different gallery based on category.

```
Cat Name1 - Album1  Album 2 Album 3
Cat Name2 - Album1   
Cat Name2 - Album1  Album 2 Album 3
Cat Name4 - Album1  Album 2
```

Each Category Icon & Thumbnail of album are in 1 row no category will show more than 4 Thumbnails

For my mobile screen width 320px & 360px i only need to show it as only one Albums

```
Cat Name1 - Album1  
Cat Name2 - Album1   
Cat Name2 - Album1
Cat Name4 - Album1
```

For my mobile screen width 480px & 640px i only need to show it only two Albums as

```
Cat Name1 - Album1  Album 2 
Cat Name2 - Album1   
Cat Name2 - Album1  Album 2 
Cat Name4 - Album1  Album 2
```

Sample HTML

```
<!-- Album Category -->
<div class="Album-Row-Wrapper"> <a href="file1.html">
        <div class="category-icon" ">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/40x150&text=A"  >
        </div>
    </a>

    <!-- Album Icon Images --> <a href="file2x?AlbumID=68&amp;">
        <div class="boxgrid"> 
            <img alt="Album One" src="http://placehold.it/150x150&text=1" >
        </div>
    </a>
 <a href="file2x?AlbumID=68&amp;">
        <div class="boxgrid"> 
            <img alt="Album One" src="http://placehold.it/150x150&text=2" >
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="file2x?AlbumID=68&amp;">
        <div class="boxgrid"> 
            <img alt="Album One" src="http://placehold.it/150x150&text=3" >
        </div>
    </a>

    <!-- Repeater Child -->
</div>
<!-- Album Category -->
<!-- Album Category -->
<div class="Album-Row-Wrapper"> <a href="file1.html">
        <div class="category-icon" ">
           <img src="http://placehold.it/40x150&text=B"  >
        </div>
    </a>

    <!-- Album Icon Images --> <a href="file2x?AlbumID=69&amp;">
        <div class="boxgrid"> 
            <img alt="Album One" src="http://placehold.it/150x150&text=1" >
        </div>
    </a>

    <!-- Repeater Child -->
</div>
<!-- Album Category -->
<!-- Album Category -->
<div class="Album-Row-Wrapper"> <a href="file1.html">
        <div class="category-icon" ">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/40x150&text=C"  >
        </div>
    </a>

    <!-- Album Icon Images --> <a href="file2x?AlbumID=68&amp;">
        <div class="boxgrid"> 
            <img alt="Album One" src="http://placehold.it/150x150&text=1" >
        </div>
    </a>
 <a href="file2x?AlbumID=68&amp;">
        <div class="boxgrid"> 
            <img alt="Album One" src="http://placehold.it/150x150&text=2" >
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="file2x?AlbumID=68&amp;">
        <div class="boxgrid"> 
            <img alt="Album One" src="http://placehold.it/150x150&text=3" >
        </div>
    </a>

    <!-- Repeater Child -->
</div>
```

I am trying to achieve this with CSS solution but it is not working properly

I want to hide album 2, 3, 4 thumbnails for each category .

I am not sure how to do it best or make it work with css.

JSFiddle Sample http://jsfiddle.net/fA2WE/1/

Comment: You had syntax errors in your CSS and the `nth-child` selector was wrong: the N's are the `a` elements, so the selector should be `.Album-Row-Wrapper a:nth-child(2) .boxgrid`. See the fixed Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fA2WE/2/

Comment: Semi-off-topic comment: why do you want to hide content (albums) for mobile devices? I'd suggest you to change the layout and present all albums in individual rows (Rows: 1st Cat A, 2nd Album I, 3rd Album II, 4th Cat B, 5th: Album I ...).

Answer (score 0):

You can use **css media queries** to achieve that:

For example:

```
/* Desktop */
@media all and (max-width: 959px) {

    #album1, #album2 {display:block;}
    #album3, #album4 {display:none;}
}

/* Tablet */  
@media all and (max-width: 720px) {

    ...

}

/* Mobile */  
@media all and (max-width: 479px) {

    #album1, #album2 {display:none;}
    #album3, #album4 {display:block;}

}
```

More about media queries and dealing with screen-sizes here: http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with bootstrap

http://jsfiddle.net/Kta7s/1/

```
@media (max-width: 640px) {
    .medium {
        display:none;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 320px) {
    .small {
        display:none;
    }
}
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-2">Cat1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-2">A1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-2 small">A2</div>
  <div class="col-xs-2 medium">A3</div>
  <div class="col-xs-2 medium">A4</div>
</div>
```